# Is there any compilation related problem in this SQL Trigger Code

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

Thanks for helping me find compilation errors in this SQL Trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trig_Agence_Compte_2
BEFORE DELETE OR UPDATE OF No
ON Agence FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    x NUMBER:=0;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) IN x FROM Compte_2@dl_RABAT WHERE Agence_No=:OLD.No;
    IF x <> 0 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20750, 'Operation Interdite : Agence Utilisee dans Compte_2');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to include the offending `:old.no` in the error message, so that in the case of a multi-row update you know which value caused the problem.

Comment: I'll do it.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have other problems, but this looks wrong to me:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) IN x FROM Compte_2@dl_RABAT WHERE Agence_No=:OLD.No;
----------------^
```

I would expect `INTO` here.